# Scikit-image difference between morphology.watershed() and segementation.watershed()

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, scikit-image

I want to apply the `Watershed` algorithm using the `skimage` library for the first time and find the documentations examples pretty confusing as there are two versions of the `watershed` given in different modules. Could someone please tell me which one can I use for **Object Detection** and/or **Object Segementation** and the link or how to use that. Please describe how the and where the other module is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skimage.morphology.watershed` is deprecated, and in the current master branch implemented by calling `skimage.segementation.watershed`. So these two functions are exactly identical. Use `skimage.segementation.watershed`.

There's an example usage [in the documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_watershed.html).